# Why missing the zero polynomial indicate subset is not closed under multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My book has the following question:

Is this a subspace of
$P_{2}: \{ a_{0} + a_{1}x + a_{2}x^2 \mid a_{0} + 2a_{1} + a_{2} = 4\}$? If it is then parametrize its description.

My reasoning for it not being a subspace is that it is not a subspace of $P_{2}$ because the subspaces would need degrees less than 2. But after thinking about it, a vector space can be a subspace for itself as a trivial subspace. Then I picked a few numbers that made the equation not equal 4, thus I concluded it is not a subspace for not satisfying closure under addtion.

The book's reason is that it is missing the zero polynomial thus not closed under multiplication. I don't understand how the zero polynomial relates to it being a subspace?

Thanks!

Comment: A subspace of a vector space is another vector space, so it needs to satisfy the vector space axioms. Not having the zero vector means that it fails the additive identity axiom, or alternatively it means that if you take any vector in the space and multiply by the scalar $0$ then you get something not in the field, meaning it fails to be closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: It is also true and easy to show that the set isn't closed under addition, but that doesn't seem to be what you've described.

Comment: @StephenDonovan I thought to check for closure under addition, we can pick specific numbers for the variables and see if that satisfies the restriction under any circumstance? and if it doesn't, then it is not closed. Please let me know if that is the wrong method?

Comment: Closure under addition means that if we start with two polynomials in the set and add them together, we must end up with another polynomial in the set. To me it sounds like you simply observed that there is a polynomial not in the set, which isn't enough on its own to prove that it's not a subspace. (there is an argument sort of similar regarding the impossibility of a non-trivial subspace of dimension $3$ but it turns out to be a bit pointless)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the following *fact*:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and let *$H$ be a subset of $V$*. We will say that $H$ is a vector subspace of $V$ $\color{blue}{\text{if, and only if}}$, the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. $\vec{0}_{V}\in H$.
> 2. For all $h_{1}$ and $ h_{2}$ in $H$, we have $ h_{1}+h_{2}\in H$.
> 3. For all $\alpha$ in $F$ and for all $h$ in $H$, we have $\alpha\cdot  h\in H$.

Now, consider the set $$H=\{a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}\in P_{2}(\mathbb{R}): a_{0}+2a_{1}+a_{2}=4\}$$
Notice that $\color{red}{H\subseteq P_{2}(\mathbb{R})}$. Thus $H$ will be a vector subspace of $P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ if, and only if, are satisfied the conditions $1),2)$ and $3)$.

Now, recall that $H$ is a subset of polynomials in $P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ which satisfies one specific condition, that is, $a_{0}+2a_{1}+a_{2}=4$.

The vector zero of $P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ under the *usual operations* is given by $$\vec{0}_{P_{2}(\mathbb{R})}=\color{red}{0}+\color{green}{0}x+\color{orange}{0}x^{2}$$
Now, the question is: *is the vector zero of $P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ in $H$?* The answer is "no" because it doesn't satisfy the conditions in $H$. Indeed, notice that
$$\color{red}{0}+2\cdot\color{green}{0}+\color{orange}{0}=0\not=4$$
Hence $\vec{0}_{P_{2}(\mathbb{R})}$ is not in $H$ and then $H$ doesn't satisfy *at least one conditions* of *fact* on this first part. Therefore $H$ is not vector subspace of $P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

---

Also you can see the conditions $2)$ and $3)$ if you want to practice. You can continue following the similar way above and see if it holds or doesn't hold. Of course, this not change the conclusion above.